# Add values to rows that don't exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a `pandas` dataframe such as this one:

```
row_number     value
1              21
3              10234
5              467
6              395
7              762

# notice row_number == 2 and == 4 are missing
```

For every *non yet existing* row where `row_number` < 10 (for instance), I'd like to insert the row with `value == 0`. That is, I'd like to get the following dataset:

```
row_number     value
1              21
3              10234
5              467
6              395
7              762
2              0
4              0
8              0
9              0
```

I can't even get to "select" these non existing rows. I tried this:

```
my_df[my_df["row_number"] == i for i in range(10) if i not in 
my_df["row_number"]]
```

But I get `invalid syntax error`.

How could I achieve what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `range` with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) of `index`:

```
df = df.set_index('row_number').reindex(range(1,10), fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
   row_number  value
0           1     21
1           2      0
2           3  10234
3           4      0
4           5    467
5           6    395
6           7    762
7           8      0
8           9      0
```

If order is important:

```
a = df['row_number'].values.tolist() + np.setdiff1d(np.arange(1,10), df['row_number'].values).tolist()
print (a)
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9]

df = df.set_index('row_number').reindex(a, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
   row_number  value
0           1     21
1           3  10234
2           5    467
3           6    395
4           7    762
5           2      0
6           4      0
7           8      0
8           9      0
```